# wxPython Window runs slow when thread loop is running in background

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a chat program I made that works the way I want it, but it runs really slow. For instance, when a few chat messages get added to the window, resizing the window gets really slow and laggy. The effect worsens as more chat messages get added.

I've narrowed it down to the server thread that is started when the program is started. If I comment out the line that starts the thread, the window is really fast and smooth regardless of how many chat messages are added.

Below is the minimum code to reproduce the issue. When run, this will create a window with  a few chat messages added and a thread looping in the background. If you try to resize the window, its is incredibly laggy. If you comment out either all the `self.AppendMessage("Username", message)` lines (removing the chat messages from the window) or `worker = SocketWorkerThread()` (stopping the thread loop), the lag will go away.

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import threading

import wx
from wx.lib.expando import ExpandoTextCtrl


class SocketWorkerThread(threading.Thread):
    """Worker Thread Class."""
    print("Server.py Started")

    def __init__(self):
        """Init Worker Thread Class."""
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            pass


class ChatWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        kwds["style"] = kwds.get("style", 0) | wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.SetSize((300, 300))
        self.SetTitle("Chat Window")

        self.panel_chat_log = wx.ScrolledWindow(self, wx.ID_ANY, style=wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)
        self.panel_chat_log.SetScrollRate(10, 10)

        self.sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.panel_chat_log.SetSizer(self.sizer_1)

        self.Layout()
        self.SetMinSize(wx.Size(300, 300))


class MyFrame(ChatWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        ChatWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.SetDoubleBuffered(True)

        # Threading causes UI to run slow
        worker = SocketWorkerThread()

        message = "Long message Long message Long message Long message Long message Long message Long message Long " \
                  "message Long message Long message Long message Long message Long message Long message Long message"

        self.AppendMessage("Username", message)
        self.AppendMessage("Username", message)
        self.AppendMessage("Username", message)

    def AppendMessage(self, username, message):
        font = wx.Font(10, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)
        height = font.GetPixelSize().Height * 1.5
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.sizer_1.Add(sizer, flag=wx.TOP | wx.EXPAND)

        text_ctrl_username = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel_chat_log, wx.ID_ANY, f"{username}: ",
                                         style=wx.BORDER_NONE | wx.TE_READONLY | wx.TE_RIGHT)
        text_ctrl_username.SetMinSize((50, height))

        sizer.Add(text_ctrl_username, 0, wx.RIGHT, 3)
        text_ctrl_username.SetFont(font)
        text_ctrl_username.SetBackgroundColour(wx.SystemSettings.GetColour(wx.SYS_COLOUR_BACKGROUND))
        text_ctrl_username.SetForegroundColour(wx.SystemSettings.GetColour(wx.SYS_COLOUR_HIGHLIGHTTEXT))

        style = wx.BORDER_NONE | wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_NO_VSCROLL | wx.TE_READONLY | wx.TE_AUTO_URL
        text_ctrl_message = ExpandoTextCtrl(self.panel_chat_log, wx.ID_ANY, message, style=style)
        sizer.Add(text_ctrl_message, 1, wx.ALL, 0)
        text_ctrl_message.SetFont(font)
        text_ctrl_message.SetBackgroundColour(wx.SystemSettings.GetColour(wx.SYS_COLOUR_BACKGROUND))
        text_ctrl_message.SetForegroundColour(wx.SystemSettings.GetColour(wx.SYS_COLOUR_HIGHLIGHTTEXT))

        self.panel_chat_log.Scroll(0, 10000000)


class MyApp(wx.App):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(False, None, False, True)
        self.ChatWindow = None

    def OnInit(self):
        self.ChatWindow = MyFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.SetTopWindow(self.ChatWindow)
        self.ChatWindow.Show()
        return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I'm not sure what to do to fix this or if I'm doing something wrong. I tried a few methods to start a thread, but they all seem to slow down the UI regardless. I can't see why the thread would even be affecting the windows operations as it is its on thing.

I saw in a few posts that were not quite the same situation I'm having, people mentioning to use `wx.CallAfter`. I tried to implement it, but it didn't make a difference. This thread is also only started once, so I don't see why it would be needed anyways.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: For a start, that thread `run` is simply racing. Throw a `time.sleep(1)` in there.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony ...This fixed it. The example code was just a striped down version. I didn't know this would fix the issue but I thought my actual code had `time.sleep(0.01)` in it, but apparently I misremembered. I'm glad it was a simple fix. Thanks a lot!